# ReactJs: change state in response to state change

Tags: javascript, state, reactjs

I've got a React component with an input, and an optional "advanced input":

```
[ basic ]
Hide Advanced...
[ advanced ]
```

The advanced on the bottom goes away if you click "Hide Advanced", which changes to "Show Advanced".  That's straightforward and working fine, there's a `showAdvanced` key in the state that controls the text and whether the advanced input is rendered.

External JS code, however, might change the value of advanced, in which case I want to show the [advanced] input if it's currently hidden and the value is different than the default.  The user should be able to click "Hide Advanced" to close it again, however.

So, someone external calls `cmp.setState({advanced: "20"})`, and I want to then show advanced;  The most straightforward thing to do would just be to update `showAdvanced` in my state.  However, there doesn't seem to be a way to update some state in response to other state changes in React.  I can think of a number of workarounds with slightly different behavior, but I really want to have this specific behavior.

Should I move showAdvanced to props, would that make sense?  Can you change props in response to state changes?  Thanks.

Comment: Setting one state depending on another state does sound like an anti-pattern. Why don’t you just check the `advanced` state in the render method?

Comment: Do you have a jsfiddle? If I understand correctly, you want to control the visibility of an element from inside your component, but also from outside right? So I would just use a prop, and have a if condition to check whether or not you should display it.

Comment: @DavidHellsing I have the same question and don't consider it an antipattern: Consider the case if the state change in response to other state change requires retrieving data from network or complex calculations. Retrieving it every time when render runs would be an antipattern on the contrary!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Okay first up, you mention that a third party outside of your component might call `cmp.setState()`?  This is a huge react no-no.  A component should only ever call it's own setState function - nothing outside should access it.

Also another thing to remember is that if you're trying change state again in response to a state change - that means you're doing something wrong.

When you build things in this way it makes your problem much harder than it needs to be.  The reason being that if you accept that nothing external can set the state of your component - then basically the only option you have is to allow external things to update your component's props - and then react to them inside your component.  This simplifies the problem.

So for example you should look at having whatever external things that used to be calling `cmp.setState()` instead call `React.renderComponent` on your component again, giving a new prop or prop value, such as `showAdvanced` set to `true`.  Your component can then react to this in `componentWillReceiveProps` and set it's state accordingly.  Here's an example bit of code:

```
var MyComponent = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function() {
        return {
            showAdvanced: this.props.showAdvanced || false
        }
    },
    componentWillReceiveProps: function(nextProps) {
        if (typeof nextProps.showAdvanced === 'boolean') {
            this.setState({
                showAdvanced: nextProps.showAdvanced
            })
        }
    },
    toggleAdvancedClickHandler: function(e) {
        this.setState({
            showAdvanced: !this.state.showAdvanced
        })
    },
    render: function() {
        return (
            <div>
                <div>Basic stuff</div>
                <div>
                    <button onClick={this.toggleAdvancedClickHandler}>
                        {(this.state.showAdvanced ? 'Hide' : 'Show') + ' Advanced'}
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div style={{display: this.state.showAdvanced ? 'block' : 'none'}}>
                    Advanced Stuff
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
});
```

So the first time you call `React.renderComponent(MyComponent({}), elem)` the component will mount and the advanced div will be hidden.  If you click on the button inside the component, it will toggle and show.  If you need to force the component to show the advanced div from outside the component simply call render again like so: `React.renderComponent(MyComponent({showAdvanced: true}), elem)` and it will show it, regardless of internal state.  Likewise if you wanted to hide it from outside, simply call it with `showAdvanced: false`.

Added bonus to the above code example is that calling `setState` inside of `componentWillReceiveProps` does not cause another render cycle, as it catches and changes the state BEFORE `render` is called.  Have a look at the docs here for more info: http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html#updating-componentwillreceiveprops

Don't forget that calling `renderComponent` again on an already mounted component doesn't mount it again, it just tells react to update the component's `props` and react will then make the changes, run the lifecycle and render functions of the component and do it's dom diffing magic.

Comment: Thanks, this was definitely the right answer.  I had some additional problems (the value that was being set and read by the external component was actually serialized/deserialized to break out the advanced/basic parts), but doing everything through props instead of calling setState externally fixed my problems.

Comment: Is there a real difference between setting the state of a react component on a child and passing to the child a callback that sets the state? Why is the first a 'huge no-no' and the second recommended and used everywhere (Ex: https://medium.com/@ruthmpardee/passing-data-between-react-components-103ad82ebd17#3698, https://material-ui.com/demos/dialogs/)?

Comment: Mike this is really insightful. So just to make sure I understand what you're saying is that a React component should not change the state of another directly? Ideally, `props` should be passed down to nested components as state changes.

However I'm not sure what to do when state needs to change in multiple places. For instance if there's an `<Input />` component I might need to pass that value up to the state of `<Form />` to group all values before submitting. Maybe I'm confusing things but it is a challenge for me to actually solve these kinds of problems. Thanks

Comment: I have the same question and don't consider it an antipattern: Consider the case if the state change in response to other state change requires retrieving data from network or complex calculations. Retrieving it every time when render runs would be an antipattern on the contrary!

Answer (score 0):

Revised answer in comment below.

---

My initial wrong answer:

The lifecycle function `componentWillUpdate` will be ran when new state or props are received. You can find documentation on it here: http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html#updating-componentwillupdate

If, when the external `setState` is called, you then set `showAdvanced` to `true` in `componentWillUpdate`, you should get the desired result.

EDIT: Another option would be to have the external call to `setState` include `showAdvanced: true` in its new state.

Comment: The doc says you can't use setState from within ComponentWillUpdate, which is why I have the problem to begin with.  I thought about having the external JS deal with the state, but that pushes component-specific logic out to consumers who shouldn't have to deal with it.

Comment: Ah, that's true. You might want `showAdvanced` to have its initial value set via `props`. Same with the `advanced_text`. Then if another component sets the `advanced_text` state, you would use logic like this in your `render`: `this.state.advanced_text || this.props.initial_advanced_text`. You could also hide the `Hide Advanced` button if `this.state.advanced_text` is set.